# Что означает строка using :::no-loc(Xamarin.Forms):::

Tags: c#, xamarin

Смотрю документацию к Xamarin.Forms и там в пример встречаю что то на подобии вот этого (отсюда https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode)

```
using :::no-loc(Xamarin.Forms):::.PlatformConfiguration;
using :::no-loc(Xamarin.Forms):::.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;
```

Однако если попробовать вставить их в код то студия подчёркивает это как ошибку и ничего не работает.

Собственно вопрос что это вообще означает и как это использовать?

Comment: Это баг сайта после недавнего выхода .net5, типа нету перевода или еще что для этой переменной, вот и сайт выдает такой "дебаг".

Comment: @EvgeniyZ А что там по идее должно быть написано?

Comment: Откройте так: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/platform/android/soft-keyboard-input-mode

Comment: @Bulson спасибо

Comment: Если видите где либо такие значения в документации Microsoft, то либо используйте как вам выше уже подсказали английский язык, либо убирайте руками (`:::no-loc(текст):::`, оставляя только текст (в вашем случае это будет `using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration;` и `using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;`)), ну а так, проблема временная, думаю скоро поправят сайт.